# app has unfortunately stoppped working after press a button

Tags: java, android

i'm suffering with app has unfortunately stopped working after i press a button i created to copy a textview onClick but when ever i click that button it crashes the app for me i still don't know what is the problem i hope you can help me guys

and thanks in advance....

this is my secondactivity.java

package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


    public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
        private Button button;
        private TextView two;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.second);
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);

       }
   });

   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
       public void onClick(View v) { 

           ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
           @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String strCopiedText;
           int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
           if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
               ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to Copy");
               clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip); 

               strCopiedText = (String) clipboard.getText(); 
               clipboard.setText(two.getText().toString());

           } else{
               strCopiedText = (String) clipboard.getText(); 
               clipboard.setText(two.getText().toString());
           }
       }
   });
   }
}
```

and this is the logcat

```
12-28 22:19:31.502: D/dalvikvm(5571): Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-28 22:19:32.152: D/dalvikvm(5571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 177K, 4% free 6832K/7111K, paused 3ms+3ms
12-28 22:19:32.182: E/ActivityThread(5571): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
12-28 22:19:32.202: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:32.202: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:32.222: I/Ads(5571): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("EC7F3FD189C6080DC9515A642B6941D1");
12-28 22:19:32.292: D/dalvikvm(5571): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads804718022.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
12-28 22:19:32.502: D/dalvikvm(5571): DexOpt: --- END 'ads804718022.jar' (success) ---
12-28 22:19:32.502: D/dalvikvm(5571): DEX prep '/data/data/imamalsajadsayings.android.com/cache/ads804718022.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 217ms
12-28 22:19:32.562: D/ViewRootImpl(5571): pckname = imamalsajadsayings.android.com
12-28 22:19:32.672: I/Ads(5571): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":0,"session_id":"1068713454932214889","u_sd":1,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"a152b5665edfefd","u_w":800,"msid":"imamalsajadsayings.android.com","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","ms":"pOmVaINaL4mmYKIl5TXd00nvOdskpqyV6XngIDvr1BWXJC2Qe5xyKQ-MItZHhMfJLyBWBno8NqgEAdlSzu56IG01HuqCzm9F5anA4LFdXsJJyKuzvOteSDNqnVocGIaaQbGOxNuOLLg8UfuBE56RJwaVEjyXdOKumCesOsg0o_zVLDgdeNakOjVC1DUCuZxk833qtkW78FaHLkZq-1Hvwb9UdQ6ctj7evmAhDRktOCEoEIiRHOELpWUd91p9konk32Y2kySRACgWPzL6yywFcaBRVNZVYx8Gwkdxu-EyPcD9_XRGUCPSP6sq8CdS55Dr2q2NuKKipk66AqF8C1e4rw","mv":"8011015.com.android.vending","isu":"EC7F3FD189C6080DC9515A642B6941D1","bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"4.android.imamalsajadsayings.android.com","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"gnt":0,"u_h":432,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
12-28 22:19:32.702: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:32.772: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:32.802: D/dalvikvm(5571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 308K, 6% free 7006K/7431K, paused 2ms+4ms
12-28 22:19:33.202: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:33.202: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:33.652: D/libEGL(5571): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-28 22:19:33.692: D/libEGL(5571): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-28 22:19:33.702: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:33.702: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:33.712: D/libEGL(5571): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-28 22:19:33.792: D/OpenGLRenderer(5571): Enabling debug mode 0
12-28 22:19:33.862: D/webviewglue(5571): nativeDestroy view: 0x14baab0
12-28 22:19:34.202: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:34.232: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:34.702: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:34.702: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:36.432: D/dalvikvm(5571): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 5% free 7097K/7431K, paused 27ms
12-28 22:19:36.432: I/dalvikvm-heap(5571): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.602MB for 614416-byte allocation
12-28 22:19:36.512: D/dalvikvm(5571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13K, 5% free 7683K/8071K, paused 3ms+6ms
12-28 22:19:36.552: D/ViewRootImpl(5571): pckname = imamalsajadsayings.android.com
12-28 22:19:36.702: D/OpenGLRenderer(5571): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-28 22:19:37.662: I/Ads(5571): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?kw&preqs=0&session_id=1068713454932214889&u_sd=1&seq_num=1&u_w=800&msid=imamalsajadsayings.android.com&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=pOmVaINaL4mmYKIl5TXd00nvOdskpqyV6XngIDvr1BWXJC2Qe5xyKQ-MItZHhMfJLyBWBno8NqgEAdlSzu56IG01HuqCzm9F5anA4LFdXsJJyKuzvOteSDNqnVocGIaaQbGOxNuOLLg8UfuBE56RJwaVEjyXdOKumCesOsg0o_zVLDgdeNakOjVC1DUCuZxk833qtkW78FaHLkZq-1Hvwb9UdQ6ctj7evmAhDRktOCEoEIiRHOELpWUd91p9konk32Y2kySRACgWPzL6yywFcaBRVNZVYx8Gwkdxu-EyPcD9_XRGUCPSP6sq8CdS55Dr2q2NuKKipk66AqF8C1e4rw&mv=8011015.com.android.vending&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&app_name=4.android.imamalsajadsayings.android.com&hl=en&gnt=0&u_h=432&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_audio=1&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&u_so=l&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=180&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a152b5665edfefd&kw_type=broad&gsb=wi&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=66&urll=914" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
12-28 22:19:37.732: I/Ads(5571): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?kw&preqs=0&session_id=1068713454932214889&u_sd=1&seq_num=1&u_w=800&msid=imamalsajadsayings.android.com&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&ms=pOmVaINaL4mmYKIl5TXd00nvOdskpqyV6XngIDvr1BWXJC2Qe5xyKQ-MItZHhMfJLyBWBno8NqgEAdlSzu56IG01HuqCzm9F5anA4LFdXsJJyKuzvOteSDNqnVocGIaaQbGOxNuOLLg8UfuBE56RJwaVEjyXdOKumCesOsg0o_zVLDgdeNakOjVC1DUCuZxk833qtkW78FaHLkZq-1Hvwb9UdQ6ctj7evmAhDRktOCEoEIiRHOELpWUd91p9konk32Y2kySRACgWPzL6yywFcaBRVNZVYx8Gwkdxu-EyPcD9_XRGUCPSP6sq8CdS55Dr2q2NuKKipk66AqF8C1e4rw&mv=8011015.com.android.vending&bas_off=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&net=wi&app_name=4.android.imamalsajadsayings.android.com&hl=en&gnt=0&u_h=432&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_audio=1&imbf=8009&u_so=l&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=180&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a152b5665edfefd&kw_type=broad&gsb=wi&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=66&urll=914
12-28 22:19:37.732: I/Ads(5571): Request scenario: Online server request.
12-28 22:19:37.962: D/OpenGLRenderer(5571): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-28 22:19:38.862: D/ViewRootImpl(5571): pckname = imamalsajadsayings.android.com
12-28 22:19:38.992: D/OpenGLRenderer(5571): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-28 22:19:40.142: D/AndroidRuntime(5571): Shutting down VM
12-28 22:19:40.142: W/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409d61f8)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at imamalsajadsayings.android.com.SecondActivity$2.onClick(SecondActivity.java:46)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-28 22:19:40.152: E/AndroidRuntime(5571):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 22:19:40.682: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:40.682: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:41.202: I/dalvikvm(5571): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:19:41.202: I/dalvikvm(5571): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:19:41.362: I/Process(5571): Sending signal. PID: 5571 SIG: 9
12-28 22:21:31.312: D/dalvikvm(5651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 180K, 4% free 6832K/7111K, paused 2ms+3ms
12-28 22:21:31.332: E/ActivityThread(5651): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
12-28 22:21:31.362: I/Ads(5651): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("EC7F3FD189C6080DC9515A642B6941D1");
12-28 22:21:31.382: I/dalvikvm(5651): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:21:31.402: I/dalvikvm(5651): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:21:31.452: D/dalvikvm(5651): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads804718022.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
12-28 22:21:31.552: D/ViewRootImpl(5651): pckname = imamalsajadsayings.android.com
12-28 22:21:31.792: D/libEGL(5651): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-28 22:21:31.802: D/libEGL(5651): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-28 22:21:31.822: D/libEGL(5651): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-28 22:21:31.852: D/OpenGLRenderer(5651): Enabling debug mode 0
12-28 22:21:31.882: I/dalvikvm(5651): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:21:31.892: I/dalvikvm(5651): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:21:34.432: D/dalvikvm(5651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 238K, 5% free 7084K/7431K, paused 3ms+4ms
12-28 22:21:34.472: D/dalvikvm(5651): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 7081K/7431K, paused 31ms
12-28 22:21:34.472: I/dalvikvm-heap(5651): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.586MB for 614416-byte allocation
12-28 22:21:34.522: D/dalvikvm(5651): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 7681K/8071K, paused 27ms
12-28 22:21:34.592: D/ViewRootImpl(5651): pckname = imamalsajadsayings.android.com
12-28 22:21:34.612: D/webviewglue(5651): nativeDestroy view: 0x163fab8
12-28 22:21:34.762: D/OpenGLRenderer(5651): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-28 22:21:35.732: D/AndroidRuntime(5651): Shutting down VM
12-28 22:21:35.732: W/dalvikvm(5651): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409d61f8)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at imamalsajadsayings.android.com.SecondActivity$2.onClick(SecondActivity.java:49)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-28 22:21:35.742: E/AndroidRuntime(5651):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 22:21:36.282: I/dalvikvm(5651): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:21:36.292: I/dalvikvm(5651): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:21:36.802: I/dalvikvm(5651): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 22:21:36.822: I/dalvikvm(5651): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 22:21:37.122: I/Process(5651): Sending signal. PID: 5651 SIG: 9
```

i hope you can help me to fix the copy to clipboard code to make the button copy the textview "two" whenever the button is clicked and thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have not instantiated `TextView` **two**. so you are getting `NullPointerException` when you call `two.getText().toString` in OnClick of button (where you are using ClipBoard)

instantiate it `onCreate()`

```
two = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in onCreate()

```
two= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate Button:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't you instantiate two buttons for r.id.button1 and r.id.button2 ! you also have two onclicklisteners setup for the same button! and of course the edittext isn't initialized as other answerers have pointed out!